# Educational discount policy at Apple and international student

Tags: macos, apple-store

I would like to know the discount amount available for educational at Apple stores and how does this apply cross-country.

Is the educational discount valid for refurbished products?

For example, if you are a student in a country where Apple does not have a store, can you get a discount and how?

Comment: What country are you in?

Comment: Before you buy - make sure you understand that where you buy your mac establishes your support and warranty in that country. You go through them first to get support so where you buy matters if you need help later.

Comment: I am live in Romania so I suppose that any EU Apple store would be required to recognize me as a student. Also I do not really care so much about the support, I am interested only about warranty and from my knowledge this is international as long you are buying from an official store (not ebay)

Comment: Here is a question regarding the education discount amount you can get http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/13968/1916

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you select the Online Apple Store for your Country, and then at the bottom of the page click on the "Education Store" link - you'll see which options you have.

Some Institutions/Schools/Educations will give you a discount without any documentation - other requires a special log-in to the Apple Store (where you typically get a better discount).

All the above for the online Apple Store - if you can get a discount in a "real" Apple Store in a Country where you don't live, I don't know for sure - but I do know that it is possible in some places of the world, if you just show some School ID.

Comment: +1 for going to http://store.apple.com/Catalog/US/Images/intlstoreroutingpage.html and just chatting with an Apple representitive to see what the sales policies are currently.